# Logic behind semaphores for threading

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I am expecting 5 results i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 yet I am getting far more? can someone please help me understand semaphores? surely as each thread calls the `run` method using "start", it should add 1 
to the int `aNumber` and then print `aNumber`.

I don't understand why I get more than five results.

```java
// mainClass creates Semaphore, so Copier class no longer needed
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
public class mainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Semaphore cp1 = new Semaphore(1, true);
        Worker[] workers = new Worker[5];
        for (int x=0;x<5;x++) {
            workers[x] = new Worker("w" + x, cp1);
        }
        for (int x=0;x<5;x++) {
            workers[x].start();
        }
        for (int x=0;x<5;x++) {
            workers[x].join();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
public class Worker extends Thread{
    int aNumber = 0;
    String myName;
    Semaphore myCopier;
    public Worker(String nameIn, Semaphore copierIn) {
        myName = nameIn;
        myCopier = copierIn;
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int x=0;x<5;x++) {
            try {
                sleep((int) (Math.random() * 5000));  // do some filing
                myCopier.acquire();
                aNumber +=1;
                //System.out.println(myName + " doing some copying");
                System.out.println(aNumber);
                sleep((int) (Math.random() * 1000));  // do some copying
                myCopier.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many is far more? Just a guess, around 25?

Comment: You create 5 workers, each counting 0-4, I'd expect 25 results.

Comment: yes correct i get 25 results, if i count each worker once, then i get 5 results, however aNumber doesn't change from 1   :(

Comment: your code runs as expected. if you run only one worker it will print 1,2,3,4,5. because you created 5 workers the result contains 5x1, 5x2, 5x3, 5x4 and 5x5. the threads run concurrently so you can get different order every time you run your application.

Comment: no when i put the 5 threads through the run method, there are indeed five results but they are: 1,1,1,1,1.

Comment: is it to do with where i am declaring the variable, aNumber. should i declare one locally?

Comment: oh sorry i didnt read your response properly Jakub, thanks a lot that is the answer

Comment: okay thanks everyone, i understand now, each thread behaves like a separate entity, and they don't really have a relationship with each other. they run, independantly, thanks jakub particularly

Answer (score 0):

I could not clearly get your intention. Are you trying to use semaphores to print the nos ( 1 to 5) in sequence by each thread? In that case, you can try the below:

```
//mainClass creates Semaphore, so Copier class no longer needed
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
public class mainClass {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     Semaphore cp1 = new Semaphore(1, true);
     Worker[] workers = new Worker[5];
     for (int x=0;x<5;x++) {
         workers[x] = new Worker("w" + x, cp1, x+1);
     }
     for (int x=0;x<5;x++) {
         workers[x].start();
     }
     for (int x=0;x<5;x++) {
         workers[x].join();
     }
 }
}


class Worker extends Thread{
    int aNumber = 0;
    String myName;
    Semaphore myCopier;
    public Worker(String nameIn, Semaphore copierIn, int no) {
        myName = nameIn;
        myCopier = copierIn;
        aNumber = no;
    }
    public void run() {
        /*for (int x=0;x<5;x++) {*/
            try {
                //sleep((int) (Math.random() * 5000));  // do some filing
                myCopier.acquire();
                //System.out.println(myName + " doing some copying");
                System.out.println("Name of the thread:" + myName + " Printed No is:" + aNumber);
                //sleep((int) (Math.random() * 1000));  // do some copying
                myCopier.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }       
        //}
    }
}
```